# When i touch the button inside the tableview it automatically goes to TabGesture method, but i want button touch method?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

Currently i am working simple iPhone application, Using UITableview to enter the field like Emp_Name, Emp_Salary etc.. and using UIButton to set a image like checkbox and set target and perform selector,
When i touch the checkbox button, it automatically comes to UITabGesture method but not comes inside the button touch method. how to fix this, please help me

I tried the source code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 UITapGestureRecognizer  *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release]; 
}

-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer // TabGesture method
{
    NSLog(@"Tab received.");
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


 if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) 
    {


        perlessonCheckButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        perlessonCheckButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30); 
        [perlessonCheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tickAltered1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [perlessonCheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPerLessonOptions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [perlessonCheckButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightTextColor]]; 
        [perlessonCheckButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:perlessonCheckButton];

    }
}



-(void) showPerLessonOptions // Button method
{
    [perlessonCheckButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [flatFeeCheckButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [perlessonCheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tickAltered1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [flatFeeCheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"untickAltered1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint tapLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(yourButton.frame, tapLocation))
    {
      [self showPerLessonOptions];
    }
}
```

Comment: is handleSingleTap is called on tapping your button ? if yes it should work. I noticed you named handleSwipeFrom while I named it handleSingleTap. You can copy paste code from my method to yours.

Comment: -(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Tab received.");    
    CGPoint tapLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(perlessonCheckButton.frame, tapLocation))
    {
        [self showPerLessonOptions];
    }

Comment: You accepted the answer, did it worked. I noticed that perlessonCheckButton is not sub view of self.view so you need to adjust frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line,

```
[perlessonCheckButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

The above line disabling the user interaction.
Change it to,

```
[perlessonCheckButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

If the above method is not working then you can add a gesture recognizer to your button.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showPerLessonOptions:)];
[perlessonCheckButton  addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[perlessonCheckButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

For more about the [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)